# Angular bootstrap Popover on hover is closing when we move outside . Popover should be open when the hover is on popover content itself

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using PopoverModule from ng-bootstrap. we have an option to open the popup on hover. In my popup i have an href link to another page. I am unable to hover over the content of the popover, then popover just disappears:

TS Code:

```
import {  PopoverModule} from 'ng-bootstrap';  

imports: [PopoverModule.forRoot()]
```

HTML Code:

```
<div  container="body" placement="bottom"  [popover]="popContent"  triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"  popoverTitle="title">
```

Could anyone help me out

Comment: Kindly mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ### CHECK [WORKING STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngbootstrap-popover-hyperlink)

**I have written a `sticky-popover.directive.ts` that can be used to achieve this functionality:~**

```
import {
  ElementRef,
  Directive, Input, TemplateRef,
  EventEmitter,
  Renderer2,
  Injector,
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
  ViewContainerRef,
  NgZone,
  OnInit,
  OnDestroy,
  Inject,
  ChangeDetectorRef
} from '@angular/core';

import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { NgbPopover, NgbPopoverConfig } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@Directive({
  selector: '[stickyPopover]',
  exportAs: 'stickyPopover'
})
export class StickyPopoverDirective extends NgbPopover implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() stickyPopover: TemplateRef<any>;

  popoverTitle: string;

  placement: 'auto' | 'top' | 'bottom' | 'left' | 'right' | 'top-left' | 'top-right' | 'bottom-left' | 'bottom-right' | 'left-top' | 'left-bottom' | 'right-top' | 'right-bottom' | ('auto' | 'top' | 'bottom' | 'left' | 'right' | 'top-left' | 'top-right' | 'bottom-left' | 'bottom-right' | 'left-top' | 'left-bottom' | 'right-top' | 'right-bottom')[];

  triggers: string;
  container: string;
  ngpPopover: TemplateRef<any>;
  canClosePopover: boolean;

  toggle(): void {
    super.toggle();
  }

  isOpen(): boolean {
    return super.isOpen();
  }

  constructor(
    private _elRef: ElementRef,
    private _render: Renderer2,
    injector: Injector,
    componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    config: NgbPopoverConfig,
    ngZone: NgZone,
    private changeRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) _document: any) {
    super(_elRef, _render, injector, componentFactoryResolver, viewContainerRef, config, ngZone, _document, changeRef);
    this.triggers = 'manual';
    this.popoverTitle = '';
    this.container = 'body';
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    super.ngOnInit();
    this.ngbPopover = this.stickyPopover;

    this._render.listen(this._elRef.nativeElement, 'mouseenter', () => {
      this.canClosePopover = true;
      this.open();
    });

    this._render.listen(this._elRef.nativeElement, 'mouseleave', (event: Event) => {
      setTimeout(() => { if (this.canClosePopover) { this.close(); } }, 100);

    });

    this._render.listen(this._elRef.nativeElement, 'click', () => {
      this.close();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    super.ngOnDestroy();
  }

  open() {
    super.open();
    setTimeout(() => {
      const popover = window.document.querySelector('.popover');
      this._render.listen(popover, 'mouseover', () => {
        this.canClosePopover = false;
      });

      this._render.listen(popover, 'mouseout', () => {
        this.canClosePopover = true;
        setTimeout(() => { if (this.canClosePopover) { this.close(); } }, 0);
      });
    }, 0);
  }

  close() {
    super.close();
  }
}
```

**Modify your `component.html`, with the custom directive to something like below:~**

```
<ng-template #popTemplate id="commentPopover">
    <div style="max-height: 6em;overflow: auto;" id="divPopover">
        {{ comment }}
    </div>
    <a href="https://yourwebpage.com" target="_blank">Open your webpage</a> 
</ng-template>
<span [stickyPopover]="popTemplate" placement="bottom" triggers="manual">
  <i class="icon">Hover over me!</i>
</span>
```

[**Also check Installation and Usage for ng-bootstrap**](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started)

**Hope this is helpful!**

Comment: I have implemented a similar solution already.. but the popover jumps to the top left of the screen on mouseleave of the InfoIcon span .

Comment: Can you reproduce the same in a stackblitz, works fine in my solution, you can use this !

Comment: The issue was with some of my css of the info icon. I have resolved it now and it is working fine

Answer (score 1):

### Update 2022

I have to thank @Sourav Dutta for this solution, it works great, But I had to make some tweaks for `Angular 13`

```
import {
  ElementRef,
  Directive,
  Input,
  TemplateRef,
  EventEmitter,
  Renderer2,
  Injector,
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
  ViewContainerRef,
  NgZone,
  OnInit,
  OnDestroy,
  Inject,
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  ApplicationRef,
} from '@angular/core';

import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { NgbPopover, NgbPopoverConfig } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@Directive({
  selector: '[stickyPopover]',
  exportAs: 'stickyPopover',
})
export class StickyPopoverDirective
  extends NgbPopover
  implements OnInit, OnDestroy
{
  @Input() stickyPopover: TemplateRef<any>;

  popoverTitle: string;

  placement:
    | 'auto'
    | 'top'
    | 'bottom'
    | 'left'
    | 'right'
    | 'top-left'
    | 'top-right'
    | 'bottom-left'
    | 'bottom-right'
    | 'left-top'
    | 'left-bottom'
    | 'right-top'
    | 'right-bottom'
    | (
        | 'auto'
        | 'top'
        | 'bottom'
        | 'left'
        | 'right'
        | 'top-left'
        | 'top-right'
        | 'bottom-left'
        | 'bottom-right'
        | 'left-top'
        | 'left-bottom'
        | 'right-top'
        | 'right-bottom'
      )[];

  triggers: string;
  container: string;
  ngpPopover: TemplateRef<any>;
  canClosePopover: boolean;

  toggle(): void {
    super.toggle();
  }

  isOpen(): boolean {
    return super.isOpen();
  }

  constructor(
    private _elRef: ElementRef,
    private _render: Renderer2,
    injector: Injector,
    viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    config: NgbPopoverConfig,
    ngZone: NgZone,
    _changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
    _appRef: ApplicationRef,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) _document: any
  ) {
    super(
      _elRef,
      _render,
      injector,
      viewContainerRef,
      config,
      ngZone,
      _document,
      _changeDetectorRef,
      _appRef
    );
    this.triggers = 'manual';
    this.container = 'body';
    this.placement = 'auto';
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    super.ngOnInit();
    this.ngbPopover = this.stickyPopover;

    this._render.listen(this._elRef.nativeElement, 'mouseenter', () => {
      this.canClosePopover = true;
      this.open();
    });

    this._render.listen(
      this._elRef.nativeElement,
      'mouseleave',
      (event: Event) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (this.canClosePopover) {
            this.close();
          }
        }, 100);
      }
    );

    this._render.listen(this._elRef.nativeElement, 'click', () => {
      this.close();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    super.ngOnDestroy();
  }

  open() {
    super.open();
    setTimeout(() => {
      const popover = window.document.querySelector('.popover');
      this._render.listen(popover, 'mouseover', () => {
        this.canClosePopover = false;
      });

      this._render.listen(popover, 'mouseout', () => {
        this.canClosePopover = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (this.canClosePopover) {
            this.close();
          }
        }, 0);
      });
    }, 0);
  }

  close() {
    super.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the above answers works great, but I wanted to make it more 'reactive' oriented. Also, in my opinion this way is a bit cleaner

```
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit, Renderer2, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentLoaderFactory } from 'ngx-bootstrap/component-loader';
import { PopoverConfig, PopoverDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/popover';
import { PositioningService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/positioning';
import { Subscription, fromEvent, merge } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  // eslint-disable-next-line @angular-eslint/directive-selector
  selector: '[stickyPopover]',
  exportAs: 'stickyPopover'
})
export class StickyPopoverDirective extends PopoverDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
  @Input() stickyPopover: string | TemplateRef<any>;

  //Note: for some reason, querySelecting by id yields null. So we create a unique class for
  //each popover method instead, and then query that. This should be refactored to use
  // popoverId = N where popover-container id='ngx-popover-N' instead when we can find a solution for the id issue.
  @Input() uniquePopoverClass: string;

  triggers: string;
  container: string;
  isHoveringOverPopover: boolean;

  subscriptions: Subscription[] = new Array<Subscription>();
  querySelectorParam: string = 'body > popover-container.';

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef<any>,
    renderer: Renderer2,
    config: PopoverConfig,
    viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    componentLoaderFactory: ComponentLoaderFactory,
    positionService: PositioningService
  ) {
    super(
      config,
      elementRef,
      renderer,
      viewContainerRef,
      componentLoaderFactory,
      positionService
    );

    //required for sticky
    this.triggers = 'manual';
    this.container = 'body';
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.subscriptions.push(
      //When pop over is shown, we subscribe to its mouse enter/leave events to determine if
      //we should close popover. If mouse entered, then pop over should stay shown even if mouse
      //left the triggering element. If mouse left, then it should force popover to hide
      this.onShown.pipe(
        switchMap(() => {
          const popoverElement = this.getPopoverElement();
          //merges observables into one subscribe, will fire subscribe when any of the observables are triggered.
          return merge(
            fromEvent(popoverElement, 'mouseenter'),
            fromEvent(popoverElement, 'mouseleave')
          );
        })
      )
      .subscribe((event) => {
        if (event.type === 'mouseenter') {
          this.isHoveringOverPopover = true;
        } else if (event.type === 'mouseleave') {
          this.isHoveringOverPopover = false;
          this.hide();
        }
      }),
      //When mouse enters the element that triggers popover
      fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'mouseenter')
      .subscribe(() => this.show()),
      //When mouse leaves the element that triggers popover
      fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'mouseleave')
      .subscribe(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (!this.isHoveringOverPopover) {
            this.hide();
          }
        }, 200);
      })
    );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    super.ngOnInit();
    this.popover = this.stickyPopover;

    //Appends the unique class for popover and the queryselector param
    if (this.uniquePopoverClass) {
      this.containerClass += ' ' + this.uniquePopoverClass;
      this.querySelectorParam += this.uniquePopoverClass;
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    super.ngOnDestroy();
    this.subscriptions.forEach(subscription => subscription.unsubscribe());
  }

  hide() {
    super.hide();
  }

  show() {
    super.show();
  }

  toggle(): void {
    super.toggle();
  }

  //querySelectorParam is useful when there will be multiple popovers implemented.
  //This allows the directive to know which exact popover
  //to listen to. If no uniquePopoverClass is inputted, then it defaults to selecting via .popover.
  private getPopoverElement() {
    if (this.uniquePopoverClass) {
      return window.document.querySelector(this.querySelectorParam);
    } else {
      return window.document.querySelector('.popover');
    }
  }
};
```

Implementation

```
 <div
          [stickyPopover]="template"
          [uniquePopoverClass]="uniqueKey + '_identifier'"
          [placement]="'left'"
          [adaptivePosition]="false"
          containerClass="popover-container"
          [outsideClick]="true">
          ...
</div>
```

I also implemented unique classes for each popover in the cases where there are multiple popovers in one page. Only using .popover to query the popover containers causes bugs with multiple popovers.